# Using PyInstaller or cx_Freeze produces very large file size with Anaconda2

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

It seems PyInstaller and cx_Freeze will include many packages with an Anaconda2 environment.

Using either will produce a file over **600MB**, this is largely due to a chain of includes which eventually includes Numpy, which then includes just about everything else.

An example of the includes that cause 600MB+ worth of packages:

```
import sys
from sys import argv
from os import path
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic, QtOpenGL
from moviepy.editor import *
```

Which doesn't seem like much, but I cannot reduce the file down without explicitly excluding Numpy, but even then it's still ~140MB and won't execute.

Has anyone had experience with dealing with this situation? 600MB is well excessive for a tiny app.

Comment: Does the executable work when you are not excluding anything?

Comment: Yep, the exe works just fine, but I need to distribute the exe, so 600MB is far too large :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was directly related to Anaconda.

When constructing an exe with Pyinstaller, it will get confused at Anaconda's package linkage and include obscene amounts of things.

This problem is fixed when using a non-Anaconda python with wheels for non-pip packages.

Comment: My own experiences suggest the same. I used to use pyinstaller in anaconda on windows to packge a small software to .exe, and it creates a folder of ~40M. Without introducing any new modules in python, now it gave me a ridiculous ~ 499M! Doing the same thing outside of anaconda, it drops to 40M again.

Comment: It is possible that Miniconda will not have this problem, as the linking is minimal.

Comment: Anaconda is definitely the issue. On a machine with an Anaconda install, the generated folder was over 600 MB. On a machine with a barebones Python + Pandas/Numpy install, it was only 100MB.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with Anaconda. You will get the same size when you use a standard Python installation.

The reason why your distribution is so big is because of the additional packages you need to supply. A very big chunk is PyQt4. This takes about 250MB of disk space for all the Qt Libraries and the Python bindings. Also as you already wrote numpy takes another big chunk of disk space (250MB on my computer). If you rely on these packages there is not much you can do to decrease the needed disk space.

However you can exclude packages you don't need. I discovered that cx_freeze likes to include packages that are installed in your Python environment regardless if you use them in your project or not. So I recommend to create a virtual environment that only contains the packages you need in your project. Also you may want to exclude tkinter from the build.